# Using PySpark to read in datalake table and can't parse timestamp column in Synapse Analytics

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I can read in the datalake table and print schema but if I try and display data I get the following error. I am working within Synapse Analytics using a PySpark Notebook and Apache Spark Pool.

See error message:

You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '10/27/2022 1:14:31 PM' in the new parser.

You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

I don't want to use the LEGACY version.

I've tried converting using the following code

```
df = df.withColumn("SinkCreatedOn",to_date(col("SinkCreatedOn"),"M/dd/yyyy h:m:s"))
df = df.withColumn("SinkModifiedOn",to_date(col("SinkModifiedOn"),"M/dd/yyyy h:m:s"))
```

I've also tried converting the suspect columns to StringType() or DateType() but no luck.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: have you tried doing what the error asks you to? should work with that

Comment: I don't want to use the legacy version and yes I have tried converting to_date but can't get it to work. I can get it to work in databricks but not synapse

Answer (score 0):

Try the script with below date format
`df = df1.withColumn("SinkCreatedOn",to_date(col("SinkCreatedOn"),"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:s a"))`

I repro'd the same with sample input. Below is the approach.

**Code:**

```py
df1=spark.createDataFrame(
data = [ ("1","Arpit","10/27/2022 1:14:31 PM"),("2","Anand","10/28/2022 1:14:31 PM"),("3","Mike","10/29/2022 1:14:31 PM")],
schema=["id","Name","SinkCreatedOn"])
df1.printSchema()
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_output = df1.withColumn("SinkCreatedOn",to_date(col("SinkCreatedOn"),"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:s a"))
df1.show()
df_output.show()
```

**df1**

[image: img1]

**df_output**

[image: img2]